# A bound on the Haussdorff distance

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be two discrete and bounded sets. Let $f_X$ be the Euclidean [signed distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function#Definition) of $X$ (similarly for $Y$) and $d_H(X,Y)$ the Euclidean [Haussdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Definition) between them.
Then, is it true that
$$ |f_X(z) - f_Y(z)| \leq d_H(X,Y) $$
for each $z \in \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: Yes it is true, in fact the optimal upper bound of the left hand side some times used as a definition of Hausdorff distance. See for example "Kreis Und Kugel" by Blaschke.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. The correct bound can be found in Theorem 2 (p. 5) of [this](https://www.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/IGDK1754/Preprints/Kraft_2015.pdf) paper.